# How do I remove songs from the IPhone App?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have syncronised folders with music and they show up nicely in the Dashboard and on the IPhone app, But when I remove a folder from syncronizing the songs are still showing up in the IPhone.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the server side as this happens to me as well. I have filed a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-music/+bug/910117